# django values_list giving id instead of value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this queryset:

```
Organisation.objects.values_list('first_parent', flat=True).distinct()
```

it gives me result like [1,2] where I need name of the organisations but when I do:

```
Organisation.objects.all()
```

its giving me name of the organisations. Whats wrong in here ?

My organisation model:

```
class Organisation(User):
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', related_name="first", blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

Comment: can you also include `Organisation` model class in your question.

Comment: I have added organisation model.. thank you for your response

Comment: it's gotta have something to do with `ForeignKey`... Try something like `Organisation.objects.filter(pk=pk).values_list('first_parent', flat=True).distinct()`

Comment: I am not using pk anywhere here.. I just want to get name of the organisation which have first_parent

Answer (score 3):

[`Field lookups`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) to use SQL **WHERE** clause to get foreign table Parent
's feild.

```
Organisation.objects.values_list('first_parent__parent_name', flat=True).distinct()
```